# Perl mongodb $collecton->find::How many roundtrips to mongodb while fetching?

Tags: perl, mongodb

If my collection has 10 records.

```
my $records = $collection->find;
while (my $record = $records->next){
   do something;
}
```

Are there ten roundtrips to the mongodb server?
If so, is there any way to limit it to one roundtrip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a single query, just like querying a RDBMS.

As per the documentation:

```
  my $cursor = $collection->find({ i => { '$gt' => 42 } });
```

Executes the given $query and returns a MongoDB::Cursor with the results

```
  my $cursor = $collection->query({ }, { limit => 10, skip => 10 });
```

Valid query attributes are:

- limit - Limit the number of results.
- skip -Skip a number of results.
- sort_by - Order results.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is it's just one query per batch of records/documents returned in groups of 100 by default.

If your result set is 250 docs, the first access of the cursor to get doc 1 will load docs 1-100 in memory, when doc 101 is accessed this causes another 100 docs to be loaded from the server, and finally one more query for the last 50 docs.

See the mongodb docs about cursors and "getmore" command.

Answer (score 2):

No, i am absolutely sure that in above code only one roundtrip to the server. For example in `c#` the same code will load all data only once, when you start iteration.

```
while (my $record = $records->next){
                               ^^^
                         here on first iteration driver load all 10 records
```

It seems to me logical have only one request to the server.

From [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors):

> The shell find() method returns a
>   cursor object which we can then
>   iterate to retrieve specific documents
>   from the result

Comment: It says: "can then iterate to retrieve...". It dosn't imply load all documents on first iteration. Further provement needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "mongosniff" tool to figure out the operations over the wire. Apart from that: you basically have no other option then iterating over the cursor....so why do you care?

Comment: In orlite there is a fetch_arrayref method. Just one round trip then return a AoH for all records. I am not sure the implication on speed.